# Is it possible to extend the standard UI

Tags: android

Is it possible to extend the standard call/message UI which is provided by native android. Is it possible to add an extra tab/scrollable item to the dial pad and messaging screen?

Thanks in advance for the replies !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't "extend" the existing apps, but you can create your own call/message UI.

The call log has an [official API](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/CallLog.Calls.html) that you can use to create your own call log (and you can check out [Android's sources](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base) to get some code or reference).

The messaging currently isn't supported by an official API, by you can still access and use it, just check out the [relevant Android sources](https://github.com/android/platform_packages_apps_mms) to get an idea about how to query for messages.